# Errors when pip install websocket-client on OSX

Tags: python, macos, websocket, macos-high-sierra

I can successfully connect my websockets client to a websockets server, but when I try to send it some message, it gives me this error:

```
error =  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connected'
```

It appears that I need to be using websockets-client instead of just websockets, so I try pip installing it and get lots of errors.  How do I resolve these errors so I can use websockets-client on python?

```
$ pip uninstall websocket
Skipping websocket as it is not installed.
$ pip install websocket-client
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.44.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from websocket-client) (1.10.0)
pyobjc-framework-mapkit 3.1.1 requires pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation>=3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc-framework-syncservices 3.1.1 requires pyobjc-framework-CoreData>=3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-Accounts==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-AddressBook==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-AppleScriptKit==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-AppleScriptObjC==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-ApplicationServices==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-Automator==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-AVFoundation==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-AVKit==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-CalendarStore==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-CFNetwork==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-CloudKit==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-Collaboration==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-Contacts==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-ContactsUI==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-CoreBluetooth==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-CoreData==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-CoreLocation==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-CoreText==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-CoreWLAN==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-CryptoTokenKit==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-DictionaryServices==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-DiskArbitration==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-EventKit==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-ExceptionHandling==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-FinderSync==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-FSEvents==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-GameCenter==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-GameController==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-ImageCaptureCore==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-IMServicePlugIn==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-InputMethodKit==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-InstallerPlugins==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-InstantMessage==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-LatentSemanticMapping==3.1.1, which is not installed.
pyobjc 3.1.1 requires pyobjc_framework-LaunchServices==3.1.1, which is not installed.
mitmproxy 0.18.3 has requirement requests<2.12,>=2.9.1, but you'll have requests 2.18.4 which is incompatible.
viper 0.0.1 has requirement ethereum==2.0.4, but you'll have ethereum 1.6.1 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` should be able to resolve your missing dependencies for you, but the two errors that you encountered are on the last two lines. Namely, you have incompatible version requirements for `requests` and `ethereum`. You could trying changing the versions of those packages, but it could end up breaking other applications on your system.

I recommend using a Python virtual environment in this case, which will ensure that your program's dependencies do not introduce dependency incompatibilities with other programs on the system.

A nice reference guide for managing packages with a virtual environment is located here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/